# How does Chrome's "Request Desktop Site" option work?

Tags: google-chrome, mobile

For iOS google chrome, when a user hits the "Request desktop site" button what does the browser do to try to bring up a desktop site? I imagine some sort of header on the request that sites are looking for, or something similar?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I think the only difference is the `User-Agent:` header in the request.

Here are the User-Agent headers sent by Chrome on my Android device:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.0.4; Galaxy Nexus Build/IMM76K) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.45 Safari/535.19
```

Notice the word "Mobile' in the first one, and also the mention of Android system and device.  Checking these, I see that it also provides false information - namely X11 and x86_64 - to closely match the value sent by the Desktop Linux version of Chrome.

Comment: A separate header would be brilliant. User Agent sniffing is so horrible.

Comment: I agree.  Sometimes the automatic detection and redirect implemented by some sites is extremely counterproductive and aggravating.

Comment: A better solution would be to detect device size, interfaces, and capabilities. CSS media queries are a step in the right direction.

Comment: This feature is not implemented by a simple UA switch and refresh. The truth of the matter is that most mobile sites will NOT switch back to desktop if loaded with a desktop UA string. So then Safari uses your original request? Nope. It seems to work even if you originally typed in the URL for the mobile site. I don't know how its implemented because the name of mobile versions is by no means standardized, but there is something smarter going on than a simple UA change.

Comment: I would like to point out that the "layout viewport" would also change if one triggers "Request Desktop Site" option, which affects media query. Check *the-mobile-web-handbook* for more infomation about layout viewport.

Answer (score 27):

Just wanted to point out that Chrome now not only changes the `User-Agent` but also ignores the original viewport meta tag if you "Request Desktop Site". Thus it won't be necessary to sniff the `User-Agent` anymore and you can rely on the viewport change as most responsive sites will automatically do. See [this Change](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/5252baa9fbff3f1ffda51a4390cdf43070af22d7) for further reference.

Comment: Thanks for that. my own very simple website is behaving very different when it isn't clicked and I couldn't understand why as I am doing nothing more than media queries in CSS.

Answer (score 17):

One other slight difference is that the request appears to have been to the last intentionally entered URL before any re-directors moved it.  For example:

**Given:** somesite.com sniffs the agent, sees Android, and does a document.location += "/m";

**Then:** the browser will have a URL of somesite.com/m

**But:** if you "Request desktop site" it will change the User-Agent and re-request from somesite.com

**Unless:** you had gone directly in on the mobile URL of somesite.com/m in the first place, in which case it just reloads somesite.com/m.

I would expect that this works with HTTP 301 and 302 redirects, I know it works with document.location changes (at least as described), and would speculate that it works with <meta> refreshes.

Comment: Did you base your answer from [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/tz24aCo6F3I)?

Comment: @Keale probably the other way around, given the timestamps

Comment: Looks like if a POST request gets a 302 or 303 suggesting a GET for another URL, then the user changes 'desktop view' setting, the browser will submit a GET request to the original URL that returned the 302/303 (losing the POST parameters).  Seems both Firefox and Chrome do this and IMO this is definitely not what should be happening.

Answer (score -2):

This javascript snippet will effectively do the same :

```js
function requestDesktopSite() {
    document.getElementsByTagName('meta')['viewport'].content='min-width: 980px;';
}
```

```html
<button onclick="requestDesktopSite()">Request Desktop Site</button>
```