# iOS User-Agent for Requesting a Desktop Site

Tags: ios, webkit

I'm trying to request a desktop site using NSURLRequest. I found from [How does Chrome's "Request Desktop Site" option work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702453/how-does-chromes-request-desktop-site-option-work) that the solution seems to be to set the User-Agent header field to mimic a desktop User-Agent string. However, simply doing

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com"];
NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[req setValue:@"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/534.53.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.3 Safari/534.53.10" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
[_webView loadRequest:req];
[self.view addSubview:_webView];
```

doesn't seem to lead me anywhere. My question is is this a correct User-Agent string I can use? Or is perhaps the request overriding the headers sometime after this?

UPDATE: 
I tried visiting http://www.useragentstring.com/ instead of facebook to see the User-Agent string at the time of the request. It seems that it's

Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_4 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/12H141

instead of the string I set. This leads me to think that the request is overriding the User-Agent sometime during the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UIWebView you're using to send the request is adding its own user agent, overriding yours. To change the user agent for your web view, try this
[Change User Agent in UIWebView (iPhone SDK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478387/change-user-agent-in-uiwebview-iphone-sdk)