# Jquery to enable "Request desktop site" mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to enable/disable the "Request desktop site" using jquery? removing/adding the  meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" is not an option cause Im using external api and the external api detecting the device and not the screen device width. [Screenshot Attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUv1t.png)

Comment: How does this have an upvote? It doesn't show us anything at all except of an image of an Android browser.

Comment: possibility of duplication : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702453/how-does-chromes-request-desktop-site-option-work

Comment: I guess this is not same issue. I need to enable/disable the  "Request desktop site"  on the mobile browser on specific page only. I'm asking if it is possible on jquery or maybe php?

Comment: You can modify meta tags with jQuery using this: `$('meta[name=author]').attr('content', 'New Author Name');`.

Comment: Removing/Deleting or Modify metatag is not possible cause it is using external api that detects the actual device not the screen width.